# Is Fluent bit supports the flunt-bit.conf file in json format?

Tags: fluent-bit

I'm trying to see whether fluent bit supports the config(fluent-bit.conf) in json format. So that I think it is easy to update the configs.

I tried converting the config into json format. But when I run fluent-bit, it is giving me the error below

```
[config] inconsistent use of tab and space
[error] [config] error in ..\conf\fluent-bit.json:2: invalid indentation level
[error] configuration file contains errors, aborting.
```

Comment: You certainly can't pretend a JSON file is `.conf`-formatted and expect it to work. The docs don't suggest any other format is accepted: https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/administration/configuring-fluent-bit/classic-mode/format-schema